# Send class object to Exception Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception

I want to implement custom exception handling in web API.

I am able to implement some initial implementation, However I want to pass class object to exception to display all attributes. like

```
    class error
    {
      int error_code
      string error_message
      string API
    }
```

When some error occur it should show json like

```
{
"error_code": 0,
"error_message":"Either Your are not authorized or you don't have any project yet.",
"API": "save data"
}
```

This code only show the message

```
throw new HttpResponseException(
                       Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message));
```

Any suggestion,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to give your object as input for the `CreateResponse` method. Generate the error response as follows,

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error, 
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

The web API will automatically json-fies the `error` object you passed.
Make sure you set the necessary values in the `error` object before you do this.
Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
Set your `HttpStatusCode` as `BadRequest` instead of `NotFound` since you are generating the exception. It's more appropriate.